# dns-search vs search option

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, resolv.conf

What is the difference between the following two entries?

- `dns-search` in `/etc/network/interfaces`
- `search` in `/etc/resolv.conf`

If they serve the same purpose, which one is the recommended to use and how to edit it?

Is there a scenario where one may shadow the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various `dns-*` entries in `/etc/network/interfaces` are used to create corresponding entries in `/etc/resolv.conf` (depending on what's actually creating `/etc/resolv.conf`, of course). From [the Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration):

> If the `resolvconf` program is installed, you should not edit the
>   `resolv.conf` configuration file manually as it will be dynamically
>   changed by programs in the system. If you need to manually define the
>   `nameservers` (as with a static interface), add a line something like
>   the following to the interfaces configuration file at
>   `/etc/network/interfaces`:
>
> ```
> dns-nameservers 12.34.56.78 12.34.56.79
> ```
>
> Place the line indented within an `iface` stanza, e.g., right after
>   the gateway line. Enter the IP addresses of the `nameservers` you need
>   to use after `dns-nameservers`. Put all of them on one line separated
>   by spaces. Don't forget the "s" on the end of `dns-nameservers`.

And [the Ubuntu LTS Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html):

> `resolvconf` uses DHCP client hooks, and `/etc/network/interfaces` to
>   generate a list of nameservers and domains to put in
>   `/etc/resolv.conf`, which is now a symlink:
>
> ```
> /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
> ```
>
> To configure the resolver, add the IP addresses of the nameservers
>   that are appropriate for your network in the file
>   `/etc/network/interfaces`. You can also add an optional DNS suffix
>   search-lists to match your network domain names. For each other valid
>   `resolv.conf` configuration option, you can include, in the stanza,
>   one line beginning with that option name with a `dns-` prefix.

Thus, `resolvconf` uses these `dns-*` entries, as well as the configuration from `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/*` to create `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: If I **only** want to add dns servers, what is the recommended way of doing it? editing `/etc/network/interfaces` or some file under `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/*`? (I do not need to set static ip or anything else)

Comment: @pkaramol if you want to keep it independent of interface configuration, then you should use a file in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d`. Use an existing file there - they're processed in the order given by the name (`head` coming first, `tail` last, etc.).